# Github actions: too many async calls?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, github-actions

I am developing a Vue application and I am importing most of the routes asynchronously to improve performance.
(*index.js*)

```
const ComponentA = () => import('path/to/ComponentA')
const ComponentB = () => import('path/to/ComponentB')

... 

export const routes = [
  {path: '/routeA', component: ComponentA},
  {path: '/routeB', component: ComponentB}
...
]
```

I have a Jest test that looks something like this:
(*index.spec.js*)

```
import ComponentA from 'path/to/ComponentA'
import ComponentB from 'path/to/ComponentB'

...

describe('router/index.js navigation test', () => {
  it('/routeA', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.findAll(ComponentA)).toHaveLength(0)
    router.push('/routeA')
    await flushPromises()
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.findAll(ComponentA)).toHaveLength(1)
  })
 it('/routeB', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.findAll(ComponentB)).toHaveLength(0)
    router.push('/routeB')
    await flushPromises()
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.findAll(ComponentB)).toHaveLength(1)
  })
...
})
```

and so on for each route. There are approximately 80 tests in this file, most of them asynchronous.

When I run the tests locally I have no issues, but when I run them with GitHub actions the tests towards the end of *index.spec.js* fail. I have tried skipping only the failing tests, but it turns out that they all fail after a certain point. Skipping the test immediately before the failing point did not help either.
What did help was splitting the very long *index.spec.js* into two separate files. I have not changed the single tests in any way, but now all tests in *index.spec.js* and *index2.spec.js* pass both locally and on GitHub actions.

Is there a limit to the stack of asynchronous calls that I am not aware of?

For reference, this is the content of the GitHub actions configuration file:
(*test.yml*)

```
name: Test
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
```

Any insights are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be related to the RATE LIMIT? (I ran into this comment for some time ago... https://github.com/hmarr/auto-approve-action/issues/6#issuecomment-516316241 but it might have evolve since then). I also don't know how the Github REST API rate limit applies to Github Actions (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/rate-limit). You could maybe add a call to the `curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/rate_limit` in your workflow to see what happens.

Comment: @GuiFalourd  Thank you for the suggestion. There is indeed a limit to the number of API calls for GitHub actions [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/usage-limits-billing-and-administration). The rate limit doesn't seem to be the issue in this case, but I was not aware it even existed, so I've learned something new. Thank you.